# Karate Bearer token from Background is coming null in Scenarios

Tags: automated-tests, token, karate, feature-file

I am new to Karate and I encounter this issue:

I have this feature class:

```
Feature: Validate myAPI
 Background:

    * def result = call read('classpath:generateBearerToken.feature')
    * def token = result.bearerToken

    * print "Token is : " + token

   * configure headers = {Authorization: '#(token)'}


  Scenario Outline: Validate POST 
   * configure headers = {Authorization: '#(token)'}
```

Now, when I print the token from background it comes as it should be but each time I try to run only a specific scenario the token comes as null.

If run the whole class, it works fine but the problem is only when I try to run from the scenario level.

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry this is the kind of question I hate the most because there is no way for anyone to answer without seeing all your code. so please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue